# Como devo subtrair arrays

Tags: php, array

```
array_intersect_ukey($result1, $result2, 'key_compare_func2') // primeiro array
array_intersect_ukey($result2, $result1, 'key_compare_func2') // segundo array
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [bife] => 3
)
Array
(
    [bife] => 2
)
```

Desejado:

```
Array
(
    [bife] => 1
)
```

Comment: Como assim? O que pretende fazer?

Comment: o adicional de um produto... ele confere o que o cliente adiciono com o produto padrao

Comment: O segundo array possui somente chaves do primeiro array, ou pode conter uma chave sem referência?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segue uma função que "mescla" as arrays, subtraindo ítens com chaves iguais em ambas:

```
function subtrai_array( $arr1, $arr2 ) {
   foreach ( $arr2 as $chave => $valor ) {
       if( array_key_exists( $chave, $arr1 ) ) {
           $arr1[$chave] = $arr1[$chave] - $valor;
      } else {
         $arr1[$chave] = -$valor;
      }
   }
   return $arr1;
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/xCMEVO)**.

Answer (score 0):

Baseado no exemplo do @Bacco, vou propor outra forma usando *array_merge_recursive*. Basicamente vai combinar os 2 arrays e gerar um array de 2 chaves quando houver combinação, depois um loop com subtração.

O exemplo considera 2 arrays (estoque e venda), onde itens de venda existem expressamente em estoque - vende apenas que está em estoque.

```
$result = array_merge_recursive($a1, $a2);

foreach ($result as $key => $value )
{
    if( is_array( $value ) )
    {
        $array[ $key ] = ($value[0] - $value[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        $array[ $key ] = $value;
    }
}
```

Exemplo no [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/NxG467), output:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| estoque    | produto.1 | produto.2 | produto.3 | produto.4 |
| quantidade | 2         | 5         | 3         | 9         |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| venda      | produto.1 |           | produto.3 |           |
| quantidade | 1         |           | 2         |           |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| resultado  | produto.1 | produto.2 | produto.3 | produto.4 |
| quantidade | 1         | 5         | 1         | 9         |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: nao sei o que aconteceu mais nao funciono

Comment: @Willian No ideone esta funcionando, quais variaveis você usou?

Comment: $fetchForm, $items['cor_id']
^estoque    ^venda

Comment: O segundo array contém as mesmas chaves do primeiro, ou contém alguma chave que não esta no primeiro array?

Comment: ([1] => 3 [6] => -2 ) pelo código do bacco reduziu a isso... agora e o seguinte o cliente pode alterar todas configurações do lanche por ex bife 3x quantidade padrao da receita ele pode retirar 1x e pode adicionar alface 1x 2x 3x no caso ele adiciono 2x entao o sistema tem que fazer uma subistituição 1 bife por 1 alface e adicional de 1 alface... entao o sistema tem que ter adicional/retirada/substituição... ao meu ver sempre vai acontecer ou substitui e adicona ou subistitui e retira /// ou apenas subistitui

Comment: contem pd a venda ela e dinâmica 100%

Comment: aqui tem uma demonstração http://jsfiddle.net/qtx8jrLy/ de como seria a parte do cliente o que ele pode fazer... ele pode remover e adicionar a quantidade que ele quizer... os que ja vem marcado e a receita padrao do produto

Comment: Essa questão já está resolvida?

Comment: sim preciso dessa nova

Comment: Então recomendo abrir uma nova questão mais detalhada.